Comedy movie about ghosts that can be sucked into vacuum cleaner

The movie is a comedy about ghosts.
The main characters, a schoolgirl and her father,
moved to a haunted house. They soon discovered that the ghosts can be
sucked into vacuum cleaners.
One of the ghosts is friendly; instead of scaring people, he became a
friend of the girl. In one scene, he secretly tied everyone in the girl's class' left and right
shoes together.
Later on, the main characters discovered a secret room in the house
and the father ended up dying due to some sort of experiment in that
room.
The friendly ghost formed a romantic relationship with the girl.
Towards the end of the movie, the friendly ghost turned back into his
human form for one hour – a handsome young man – so he could dance
with the girl at the ball.
Possibly made during the 90s or early 2000.

What movie is this?

The movie is Casper (1995), the live adaptation of the old comic/cartoon Casper.
The shoes scene:



(I only found this non-english version clip of the shoes part)
The vacuum scene:



